# Could not extract text from python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have written following code to extract price detail the url.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36')
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)
driver.get("https://www.walmart.com/ip/Fitness-Reality-TR3000-Maximum-Weight-Capacity-Manual-Treadmill-with-Pacer-Control-and-Heart-Rate-System/37455841#")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[itemprop='price']:nth-of-type(1)").text
```

It is giving empty value although we have price details inside that particular tag.

When I tried extracting `innerHTML`of that tag instead of `text` using the following.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[itemprop='price']:nth-of-type(1)").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

I get these results

```
u' <span class="Price-sup">$</span>199<span class="Price-mark">.</span><span class="Price-sup">00</span> '
```

It clearly shows that I have text `199` inside the tag but I couldnt extract it. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Do you need just a `199` value or `$199.00`?

Answer (score 0):

To get price you need following code:

```
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@itemprop="price"]').text
# due to hidden element <span class="Price-mark">.</> 
# you need to specify floating point by yourself
# or you will get $19900 as result which is not what you expect 
price = '.'.join([price[:-2], price[-2:]])
```

Result: `$199.00`

Comment: can i get the version of find_element_by_css_select() instear of xpath.....i have only css selectors and thats wat not working

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@itemprop="price"]')` == `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[itemprop="price"]')`

Comment: i triied the same ..but getting a blank text...are you using phantomjs driver?

Comment: No, tested with `chromedriver`. For now I cannot test it with `PhantomJS`. Is it mandatory to use `PhantomJS`? It has a lot of similar unresolved issues...

Comment: yeah ..i am using it with ubuntu headless machine....if i use chrome or firerfox i need to do it with pyvirtual display...which is again a pain to use